# C# application passing an object from on form to another

Tags: c#

In my application Main loads form 1, in form 1 an object is created. There is a next button on form 1, when next button is clicked form 1 is hidden and form 2 is loaded. I am trying to pass the object created in form 1 to form 2, but the data in the object is not being pulled to form 2, what am I doing wrong?

Class1 has

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab15
{
public class Reservation
{
    //set private instance variables
    private int checkInDateDay;
    private int checkInDateMonth;
    private int checkInDateYear;
    private int numberOfNights;
    private int numberofGuests;
    private string name;
    private string addressStreet;
    private string addressCity;
    private string addressState;
    private int addressZipCode;
    private string creditCardNumber;
    private decimal dailyRate;
    private decimal subTotal;
    private decimal tax;
    private decimal total;
    private string phone;

    // CheckInDateDay property
    public int CheckInDateDay
    {
        get { return checkInDateDay; }
        set { checkInDateDay = value; }
    } // end CheckInDateDay property

    // CheckInDateMonth property
    public int CheckInDateMonth
    {
        get { return checkInDateMonth; }
        set { checkInDateMonth = value; }
    } // end CheckInDateMonth property

    // CheckInDateYear property
    public int CheckInDateYear
    {
        get { return checkInDateYear; }
        set { checkInDateYear = value; }
    } // end CheckInDateYear property

    // NumberOfNights property
    public int NumberOfNights
    {
        get { return numberOfNights; }
        set { numberOfNights = value; }
    } // end NumberOfNights property

    // NumberofGuests property
    public int NumberofGuests
    {
        get { return numberofGuests; }
        set { numberofGuests = value; }
    } // end NumberofGuests property

    // Name property
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    } // end Name property

    // AddressStreet property
    public string AddressStreet
    {
        get { return addressStreet; }
        set { addressStreet = value; }
    } // end AddressStreet property

    // AddressCity property
    public string AddressCity
    {
        get { return addressCity; }
        set { addressCity = value; }
    } // end AddressCity property

    // AddressState property
    public string AddressState
    {
        get { return addressState; }
        set { addressState = value; }
    } // end AddressState property

    // AddressZipCode property
    public int AddressZipCode
    {
        get { return addressZipCode; }
        set { addressZipCode = value; }
    } // end AddressZipCode property

    // CreditCardNumber property
    public string CreditCardNumber
    {
        get { return creditCardNumber; }
        set { creditCardNumber = value; }
    } // end CreditCardNumber property

    // DailyRate property
    public decimal DailyRate
    {
        get { return dailyRate; }
        set { dailyRate = value; }
    } // end DailyRate property

    // SubTotal property
    public decimal SubTotal
    {
        get { return subTotal; }
        set { subTotal = value; }
    } // end SubTotal property

    // Tax property
    public decimal Tax
    {
        get { return tax; }
        set { tax = value; }
    } // end Tax property

    // Total property
    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return total; }
        set { total = value; }
    } // end Total property

    // Phone property
    public string Phone
    {
        get { return phone; }
        set { phone = value; }
    } // end Phone property

    // Reservation Constructor
    public Reservation(int checkInDateday, int checkInDateMonth, int checkInDateYear, 
                       int numberOfNights, int numberofGuests, string name, 
                       string addressStreet, string addressCity, string addressState, 
                       int addressZipCode, string creditCardNumber, decimal dailyRate, 
                       decimal subTotal, decimal tax, decimal total, string phone)
    {
        CheckInDateDay = checkInDateDay;
        CheckInDateMonth = checkInDateMonth;
        CheckInDateYear = checkInDateYear;
        NumberOfNights = numberOfNights;
        NumberofGuests = numberofGuests;
        Name = name;
        AddressStreet = addressStreet;
        AddressCity =addressCity;
        AddressState = addressState;
        AddressZipCode = addressZipCode;
        CreditCardNumber = creditCardNumber;
        DailyRate = dailyRate;
        SubTotal = subTotal;
        Tax = tax;
        Total = total;
        Phone = phone;
    } // end Reservation Constructor

}
}
```

Form1 has

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lab15
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int checkInDateDay = checkInDateDateTimePicker.Value.Day;
        int checkInDateMonth = checkInDateDateTimePicker.Value.Month;
        int checkInDateYear = checkInDateDateTimePicker.Value.Year;
        int numberOfNights = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfNightsNumericUpDown.Value);
        int numberofGuests = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfGuestsNumericUpDown.Value);
        string name = "";
        string addressStreet = "";
        string addressCity = "";
        string addressState = "";
        int addressZipCode = 0;
        string creditCardNumber = "";
        decimal dailyRate = 0.00m;
        decimal subTotal = 0.00m;
        decimal tax = 0.00m;
        decimal total = 0.00m;
        string phone = "";

        Reservation newRes = new Reservation(checkInDateDay, checkInDateMonth, checkInDateYear, numberOfNights,
                       numberofGuests, name, addressStreet, addressCity, addressState,
                       addressZipCode, creditCardNumber, dailyRate, subTotal, tax,
                       total, phone);

        this.Hide();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(newRes);
        form2.Show();
    }


}
}
```

Form2 has

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lab15
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Reservation newRes;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(Reservation newRes)
    {
        this.newRes = newRes;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int day = newRes.CheckInDateDay;

        label5.Text = Convert.ToString(day);

    }

}
}
```

In form 2, I am using the next button to populate a label instead of what it should be doing just to check the value.

Comment: That code all looks fine, can you give an example of the error you are seeing?

Comment: @DanielCook There is no error, the value is just showing 0 instead of what it should be.

Comment: OK, stick a breakpoint in the call to new Form2(newRes) and check the values in there.

Comment: @DanielCook I am sorry but I have never learned how to use breakpoints, I am still pretty new to C# and just now learning how to do applications in C#. I figured out how to add a breakpoint but where do I see the  variables being passed?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, you can right-click on the line and select add breakpoint (or select the code and press F9).

Comment: @DanielCook okay so I checked the breakpoint and all of the data is there. Thanks for teaching me how to use that, I think that will be handy in the future :) value of the var being passed is 6 but when I assign the var in from 2 to say a label it passes the value of 0

Comment: Now, I would do the same in the constructor of Form2 and check it again. Then stick another one on the bit of code where the data is missing and check again.

Comment: Okay, I added another breakpoint in form2 in order to check and it is showing the value as 0

Comment: I think you will have to share some more of your code to let us help, nothing appears incorrect from what you've posted so far.

Comment: @DanielCook okay, I added the class and all of form1 and form2. I am just checking the value of 1 variable on the "next" button on form 2. If I can get 1 to work then all should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your constructor for the `Reservation` class.  You are setting `CheckInDateDay = checkInDateDay`.  However, your parameter to the constructor is `checkInDateday` (notice the lowercase d in "day").  Since your field in the `Reservation` class is `checkInDateDay`, the line `CheckInDateDay = checkInDateDay` is setting the field/property to itself (instead of setting `CheckInDateDay` to the value that you're passing into the constructor like you expect).  Change the parameter in your constructor to `checkInDateDay` (capital D) and it should work.

To prevent these sorts of problems with variables and fields having the same or similar names which allows your code to compile without an error but not do what you expect, it's common practice to have fields begin with an underscore.  For example

```
public class Reservation
{
   private int _checkInDateDay;

   public int CheckInDateDay
   {
      get { return _checkInDateDay; }
      set { _checkInDateDay = value; }
   }
}
```

Also, there's no reason to have the fields in your case.  Just let your properties be auto implemented, like this.

```
public class Reservation
{
   public int CheckInDateDay { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That was a good spot! I agree with the use of auto-properties, in this case it would have prevented your issue as the backing fields are generated with _ as a prefix.